# HOW TO: asp.net form windows authentication on the specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, windows-authentication

I am developing asp.net webforms and I use Windows Authentication in my web application(for intranet). How I can identify permission for access on the specific page.

Like `<deny roles=""/>` in the web.config for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify which location to apply authorization for:

```
<location path="MyPage.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>        
      <deny roles=""/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This means you can apply authorization rules related to specific page

Comment: I tried to implement this solution and i have an error: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.